# What terms to differentiate between a quasi-synchronous motor (eg an induction motor ) and a completely asynchronous motor (eg a universal motor)?

Tags: motor, ac, induction-motor

I am editing a [table of motors](http://liionbms.com/php/motors.php).

I am looking for the correct terms to distinguish two types of motors: motors whose speed is less than the AC frequency (all inductions / squirrel cage motors) from motors whose speed is completely independent of the AC frequency (universal motors and repulsion motors).

Normally, the former is called "asynchronous" thought they are "quasi-synchronous".

What about the latter? They are too "asynchronous" but they are *completely* asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand, electrically and magnetically

- synchronous machine and brushed DC machine are twins
- asynchronous machine and transformer are twins

(The repulsion motor is a special sort of asynchronous machine. The brushless DC motor is a special sort of synchronous machine.)

So your categories make very little sense. That's why there isn't a term for it.

In case you wonder, the brushed DC machine is synchronous to its own speed, that's what the commutator is for. Because it's always synchronous, you can feed any frequency to it, given that the field current is in phase with the rotor current. In an universal motor, that's ensured by putting the field and rotor winding in series.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are trying to state a difference in "asynchronous" versus "quasi-synchronous", but I think that's not really valid; "a"... = not, "quasi..." = partly or almost, which would fall under "not" as well. But I see your other point IF you are defining AC motors as being frequency dependent or not, because your unknown class (universal and repulsion) although still "not" synchronous as well, get there in a different way.

I vote for "synchronous", "asynchronous", and "unfettered" AC motors. Unfettered meaning their speed is not tied to the AC source.

Comment: > unfettered ... 
I like that.

Comment: To be honest, it was the result of a peek at the thesaurus...